# Android skipping code

Tags: java, android

I'm experiencing a (in my view) really weird problem. I have an Android Project in Android Studio containing the following code:

```
if(AppSettings.isNetworkAvailable(context, showDialog)) {
return null;
}
else {

    HttpResponse httpResponse = null;
    AsyncHttpGet asyncHttpGet = new AsyncHttpGet(mHttpClient, mHttpContext);

    String url = BASE_URI + atPath;
    asyncHttpGet.execute(url);

    try {
        httpResponse = asyncHttpGet.get();
        System.out.println("Response: " + httpResponse);
    } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    if(isAccepted(httpResponse)) {
        return httpResponse;
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

This code returns null at runtime and gives no output. The debugger cursor jumps from the first if-clause (which returns true) directly to the last return statement without declaring or initializing any of the variables.

I have also tried removing the else as it should work without it, but that makes no difference. Does anyone have an idea where the problem could be?

EDIT: I should add: the code works just fine without the initial if-clause and returns a valid HttpResponse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if the `AppSettings.isNetworkAvailable(context, showDialog)` is true,  `return null` is the correct behaviour.

If you want to enter the else part, use this:

```
if(AppSettings.isNetworkAvailable(context, showDialog)) {
    HttpResponse httpResponse = null;
    AsyncHttpGet asyncHttpGet = new AsyncHttpGet(mHttpClient, mHttpContext);

    String url = BASE_URI + atPath;
    asyncHttpGet.execute(url);

    try {
        httpResponse = asyncHttpGet.get();
        System.out.println("Response: " + httpResponse);
    } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    if(isAccepted(httpResponse)) {
        return httpResponse;
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: you missed one return statement

Comment: Thanks, that really was the "problem"! 3 guys, 1 hour of debugging, and nobody saw that... I guess the debugger jumping was just due to some optimizing of the return statements.